# Reading an ambiguous datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime, dst

Consider the following:

```
> as.POSIXct('2021-11-07 01:30', tz='US/Central')
[1] "2021-11-07 01:30:00 CST"
```

Note how I got `CST`. What if I wanted `'CDT'`?

In Python-pandas, I can use `ambiguous`:

```py
In [5]: pd.Timestamp('2021-11-07 01:30:00').tz_localize('US/Central', ambiguous=False)
Out[5]: Timestamp('2021-11-07 01:30:00-0600', tz='US/Central')

In [6]: pd.Timestamp('2021-11-07 01:30:00').tz_localize('US/Central', ambiguous=True)
Out[6]: Timestamp('2021-11-07 01:30:00-0500', tz='US/Central')
```

Comment: `lubridate::force_tz(dt, tzone_out = "CDT")` or `force_tz(dt, roll_dst = "post")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [clock's](https://clock.r-lib.org/) `date_time_parse()`, then that will error by default on ambiguous date times. You use `ambiguous` to decide how to handle them, which allows you to choose either the earliest or latest possible option:

```r
library(clock)

# Error by default
date_time_parse("2021-11-07 01:30", zone = "US/Central", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#> Error in `stop_clock()`:
#> ! Ambiguous time due to daylight saving time at location 1.
#> ℹ Resolve ambiguous time issues by specifying the `ambiguous` argument.

# CDT
date_time_parse("2021-11-07 01:30", zone = "US/Central", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", ambiguous = "earliest")
#> [1] "2021-11-07 01:30:00 CDT"

# CST
date_time_parse("2021-11-07 01:30", zone = "US/Central", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", ambiguous = "latest")
#> [1] "2021-11-07 01:30:00 CST"
```

Answer (score 1):

It normally shows "CST"

```
seq(as.POSIXct("2021-11-07 01:58", tz="US/Central"), 
  as.POSIXct("2021-11-07 02:03", tz="US/Central"), "min")
[1] "2021-11-07 01:58:00 CST" "2021-11-07 01:59:00 CST"
[3] "2021-11-07 02:00:00 CST" "2021-11-07 02:01:00 CST"
[5] "2021-11-07 02:02:00 CST" "2021-11-07 02:03:00 CST"
```

but we can trick it to show the previous "CDT" by going back an hour (3600 secs)

```
seq(as.POSIXct("2021-11-07 01:58", tz="US/Central") - 3600, 
  as.POSIXct("2021-11-07 02:03", tz="US/Central") - 3600, "min")
[1] "2021-11-07 01:58:00 CDT" "2021-11-07 01:59:00 CDT"
[3] "2021-11-07 01:00:00 CST" "2021-11-07 01:01:00 CST"
[5] "2021-11-07 01:02:00 CST" "2021-11-07 01:03:00 CST"
```

In your case

```
as.POSIXct("2021-11-07 01:30", tz="US/Central") - 3600
[1] "2021-11-07 01:30:00 CDT"
```